# Changing font size of colorbar TickLabels in Matlab automatically

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I change font size of colorbar TickLabels in Matlab automatically?
I know I can change the font using

```
c = colorbar;
c.Label.String = 'string';
c.Label.FontSize=16;
```

But couldn't find how to change the fontsize of ticks.

[image: Font size of labels is increased but not the ticklables]

Comment: What do you mean? `c.Label.FontSize=16;` is how you change the font size, as the name `FontSize` suggest.

Comment: It does not change the font size of Ticklables. It changes  the font size of label.

Comment: Try changing `c.FontSize`.

Comment: Thanks Navan. I don't know how I missed that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be referring to the thickness of the ticks, which you can change with the property

```
c.LineWidth
```

or you can change the font size of the ticks with

```
c.FontSize
```

There are a lot of other properties you can play with, in 2018b specifically, these are the modifiable properties and their default values:

```
        AxisLocation: 'out'
    AxisLocationMode: 'auto'
        BeingDeleted: 'off'
                 Box: 'on'
          BusyAction: 'queue'
       ButtonDownFcn: ''
            Children: [0×0 GraphicsPlaceholder]
               Color: [0.1500 0.1500 0.1500]
           CreateFcn: ''
           DeleteFcn: ''
           Direction: 'normal'
           FontAngle: 'normal'
            FontName: 'Helvetica'
            FontSize: 9
          FontWeight: 'normal'
    HandleVisibility: 'on'
             HitTest: 'on'
       Interruptible: 'off'
               Label: [1×1 Text]
              Limits: [0 1]
          LimitsMode: 'auto'
           LineWidth: 0.5000
            Location: 'eastoutside'
              Parent: [1×1 Figure]
       PickableParts: 'visible'
            Position: [0.8307 0.1095 0.0381 0.8167]
            Selected: 'off'
  SelectionHighlight: 'on'
                 Tag: 'Colorbar'
       TickDirection: 'in'
TickLabelInterpreter: 'tex'
          TickLabels: {11×1 cell}
      TickLabelsMode: 'auto'
          TickLength: 0.0100
               Ticks: [0 0.1000 0.2000 0.3000 0.4000 0.5000 0.6000 0.7000 0.8000 0.9000 1]
           TicksMode: 'auto'
                Type: 'colorbar'
       UIContextMenu: [1×1 ContextMenu]
               Units: 'normalized'
            UserData: []
             Visible: 'on'
```

If its not here, you can not change it.